# Pure Regex to include one phrase and NOT include another

Tags: regex

We are trying to create a regex that will identify when a line includes our CEO's name, but isn't coming from their email address. Since this is being done in our email system (Google Workspace), we cannot script this and it needs to be all done in regex.

Here are two examples of lines in the email headers:

```
From: Mr Robotto <hzdmhzkq@gmail.com>

From: Mr Robotto <mrrobotto@mycompany.com>
```

We want to capture email headers that include `From: Mr Robotto` but aren't followed by `mrrobotto@mycompany.com` on the same line. So the first example above should be positively identified and the second should not.

I believe I need to use a negative lookaround, but cannot seem to get it right. Here's what I'm using so far:

```
"^(?!from\:\smr\srobotto\s<mrrobotto\@mycompany\.com>)\/(from\:\smr\srobotto)\/.*"
```

Comment: Use a negative lookahead to match if it doesn't contain their email.

Comment: i think i was possibly doing a lookbehind in my example? 
After researching further I think I solved it with this lookahead:

(?i)from\:\mr\srobotto\s(?!\<mrrobotto\@mycompany\.com)

Comment: That looks about right. You should add `>` at the end of the email. FYI, you don't need to escape `:` or `@`, they have no special meaning in regexp.

Comment: perfect, thank you! FYI, here's what I ended up with:


(?i)from:\smr\srobotto\s(?!<mrrobotto@mycompany\.com>)